# Reference for ASP.NET Identity needed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

How do I use **ASP.NET Identity** into *empty* web projects?

Comment: Additionally there are some [articles](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/) from Brock Allen about ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't do the google-ing for you, I just happened to be doing some research myself and came across the following resources.

Two good blog posts on odetocode.com [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/25/asp-net-core-identity.aspx) and [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/03/asp-net-identity-with-the-entity-framework.aspx).

On the subject of empty web projects (taken from comments from above links):

> People who want to start from scratch are usually looking to do something like create a .Domain or .Core assembly with their own definition of a user that can plug into the Identity framework. Unfortunately, this means you either take a dependency on the Entity Framework in a domain assembly (to inherit from IdentityUser) or re implement IUser and IUserStore from scratch. It's also much easier to use classes like ApplicationUser for a new application but a bit difficult to manage with an existing schema until you've figured out all the pieces (like how to do mapping with EF).

There is also the Identity Database template which has all the scripts, UDTs etc. used in ASP.NET Identity, available [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6780f8e4-d204-4e88-83c2-853098727ffb).